# No response from API using AJAX request

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

I'm trying to connect to API using AJAX request, however I get no response. Whether it's an problem with my header, or something else - it's difficult to debug it when I can't see the any errors in console.

This is my AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.partners.bazoeka.com/latest/api/postcodecheck?&format=json',
        method: 'GET',
        crossDomain: true,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('username:myUsername', 'password:myPassword','apikey:apiKey');                  
    }

   }).done(function () {
         console.log("connected!");
         //do stuff
        });
```

The documentation from this API provides very little information:

> Authentication is done by passing the username, password and API key in the header of
>   the HTTP(S) request. For all functions authorization is required. So to be able to do a
>   successful call you have to pass a username, password and an API key

I know my credentials are correct, request works fine with cURL:

```
 curl  -H"username:myUsername" -H"password:myPassword" -H "apikey:apiKey" "https://api.partners.bazoeka.com/latest/api/postcodecheck?&format=json&postcode=1010AA&housenr=1"
```

Could the problem be the headers in my AJAX request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xhr.setRequestHeader()` should accept a key and a value, if you want to add multiple headers, try to add a `xhr.setRequestHeader()` for each header

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('username', 'MyUsername');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('password', 'MyPassword');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('apikey', 'apikey');  
}
```

see doc:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader

Comment: Thank you, this might be the solution, however now I get a different error: _Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin http://localhost is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500._

Comment: This is a CORS rule, it means that the remote host is not accepting you. I don't know this is because you are in localhost, you should try to contact them or try with a reachable origin https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Answer (score 0):

According to the jQuery documentation, the ajax request will not be performed, if the callback function in beforeSend will return false.
And I think, setRequestHeader will need 2 arguments, the header name and the header value.
Could you try a call to setRequestHeader for each header like:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('username', 'myUsername');
xhr.setRequestHeader('password','myPassword');
xhr.setRequestHeader('apikey' , 'apiKey');
```

Even better, pass the additional headers as object to your ajax config:

```
...
headers: {
username: 'myUsername',
password: 'myPassword',
apikey: 'apikey
},
...
```